# Selenium webdriver ruby assertTextPresent

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, assert

I have written a below code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)

driver.navigate.to("http://www.yahoo.co.uk")

assert(@driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("News"))

driver.find_element(:link_text, "News").click

driver.quit
```

but getting below error:

```
C:/RubyTito/FirstRuby/RSpec.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `find_element' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The script opens the ff but stops at line 4. What i wanted to achieve is the script should open the ff find the News link (give some message TRUE) and then click on the news link.

Answer (score 0):

@driver was not determined in your code

**btw:**
@driver is an instance variable - and is available to all methods within the class.

driver is a local variable. They only exists within it's scope (current block)

[more information](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants)

solution #1:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
driver.navigate.to("http://www.yahoo.co.uk")

if driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("News") # true or false
  puts "News link present on page"
  driver.find_element(:link_text, "News").click
else
  puts "News not found"
end

driver.quit
```

solution #2: (run as rspec this_file.rb)

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"

describe "Yahoo Search" do

  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://www.yahoo.co.uk"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit   
  end

  it "click on News link" do
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @driver.find_element(:tag_name => "body").text.include?("News")
    @driver.find_element(:link_text, "News").click
  end

end
```

also you can use [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vetal4eg ! I tried your solution but giving different error C:/RubyTito/FirstRuby/RSpec.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `assert' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: How to get over this error. C:/RubyTito/FirstRuby/RSpec.rb:4:in <main>': undefined method assert' for main:Object (NoMethodError) while running the above script .

Comment: This assumes you are using a standard testing framework, such as TestUnit or MiniTest that includes the assert method.

Comment: I am not sure which testing framework i am using. I installed Eclipse and Running ruby inside Eclipse.

Comment: Can anybody guide me in the right direction. What steps i am missing. Is there need to install something.

Comment: tried Solution 2 showing below error : C:/RubyTito/FirstRuby/rspec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `describe' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
 from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 from C:/Users/basam/RubyTito/FirstRuby/RSpec.rb:2:in `<main>'